# Encoding console russian sumbols input

Tags: java, encoding, console, symbols, cyrillic

I have encoding trouble with russian simbols. Firstly I have decided console output problem with this code:

```
String consoleEncoding = System.getProperty("consoleEncoding");
if (consoleEncoding != null) {
    try {
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out, true, consoleEncoding));
    } catch (java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        System.err.println("Unsupported encoding set for console: "+consoleEncoding);
    }
}
```

but I have console `Scanner` input that can have russian symbols too, but if will make like this

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
String text = sc.nextline(); //if user input here eg "Привет,Мир"
System.out.println(text); // here I will recieve "???,??"
```

Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in, "UTF-8);

or "cp866" will not work for me (or will work only for Windows) I need such universial decision that can adapt and accept input russian characters to any OS console (mac OS/win)

Answer (score 1):

```
Locale loc = new Locale("ru");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in, "UTF-8");
sc.useLocale(loc);
```

Comment: thank you for fast answer, will it works only for mashines that located in russian region ?

Comment: The method `useLocale(Locale locale)` sets this scanner's locale to the specified locale. It's the `Scanner sc` which will use `Russian Locale`. It has nothing to do with machines located in the russian region.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not help

Comment: you can use `Locale dLocale = new Locale("ru");` from the [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/locale/create.html)

Comment: It still gives me output like ?аЁў?в, ?Ёа (when mine input is "Привет, Мир"

Answer (score 0):

Locale did nothing for me. The file should be saved as UTF-8, and the console you run the program with has to use UTF-8 too. I just run the program through eclipse when I need to use russian characters, and that works for me. To save as UTF-8, right click the file in package explorer -> Properties -> Text file encoding, select Other, type UTF-8.